# Using sqlite3_column_text() to fetch interger value

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite

I have a table with `TEXT`, `INTEGER`, `REAL` and other data types.

I wrote a generic sql function to read results for all queries using `sqlite3_column_text()` like so:

`char *dataAsChar = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, ii);`

Although I should be using `sqlite3_column_int` etc. to read the numeric values, the above code seems to work for me. I get the number values as string which I later convert to int using `[*numberAsString* intValue]`.

Since I am using a generic function to read all my db values, this is very convenient for me. **But is there something that can go wrong with my code?**

I could use `sqlite3_column_type` for each column to determine the type and use appropriate function. Am I correct in assuming that `sqlite3_column_text` basically returns the column value in `TEXT` format and does not necessarily need the value itself for be `TEXT`?

The only situation where I can see this implementation failing is with `BLOB` data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) says:

> These routines attempt to convert the value where appropriate. […]
>   The following table details the conversions that are applied:
>
> ```
> Internal Type  Requested Type  Conversion
> NULL           TEXT            Result is a NULL pointer
> INTEGER        TEXT            ASCII rendering of the integer
> FLOAT          TEXT            ASCII rendering of the float
> BLOB           TEXT            Add a zero terminator if needed
> ```